# OpenGL Texture Binding / Rendering

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

This is my first attempt to get texture mapping to work.

This is my implementation:

Global Fields:

```
GLuint texture[big];            // Storage for some Textures
int globalcounter;
```

Mesh Draw:

```
ApplyMaterial(mesh->Materials());  //set material properties,works fine
DrawSingleObject(*mesh);
```

The draw method:

```
DrawSingleObject(Mesh& p){

QList<Face>& faces=p.Faces();
int NumberOfFaces=faces.count();
QList<Vector3D>& normals =p.Normals();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glGenTextures(1, &texture[globalcounter]);                  // Create The Texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[globalcounter]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 256 , 256 , 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p.Mat().GetTexture()->Data() );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

for (int t = 0; t < NumberOfFaces; ++t) {
    Face& f = faces[t];
    GLenum face_mode;
    int* lista=f.arrayVertici;
    const QList<Vector3D> vertices=p.Vertices();

    int* listaNorm=f.normalIndex;
    switch(f.VertexNumber) {
    case 1:
        face_mode = GL_POINTS;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if(hasNormals)
            glNormal3fv(&((normals[listaNorm[0]]).pos[0]));
        glTexCoord2f(?);    
        glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);                    
        break;
    case 2:
        face_mode = GL_LINES;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if(hasNormals){
            glNormal3fv(&((normals[(f.normalIndex)[0]]).pos[0]));
            glTexCoord2f(?);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glNormal3fv(&((normals[(f.normalIndex)[1]]).pos[0]));
            glTexCoord2f(?);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
        }
        else{
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if(hasNormals){
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(?);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[1]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(?);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[2]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(?);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[2]].pos[0]);

        }
        else{
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[2]].pos[0]);
        }
        break;
    default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
    }
    glEnd();

}
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Mesh has these fields:

```
QList<Vector3D> mTextureCoords;     //contains Textures coordinates
Material mMat;
```

Material has this field:

```
Texture* mTexture;
```

Texture has this field:

```
QImage* mImage;                     
a dedicated pointer to mImage->bits()
```

Texture is now correctly loaded to mImage.

***Questions:***

- Binding: is it correct to bind the texture before the vertex draw?is this a correct implementation?
- Could you explain me how to use Vector3D texture coords to load texture on a specific mesh?I think my main problem is that I render iterating through faces,while the textures' vertex list is generic (binded to a mesh and not to faces).

Comment: Yes, you need to bind your texture before drawing an object that should have it mapped onto it. As for the texture coordinates, usually you use two-dimensional coordinates in a form known as normalized coordinates - they have a range 0.0 - 1.0, anything outside this range is subject to something known as wrapping. Look up `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Edge_value_sampling) for more info.

Comment: Note that textures created with `glGenTextures` need to be released with `glDeleteTextures` to avoid memory leaks. It's better to create the texture outside the draw function then reuse it or update its data if the content changes. The code would look better even if `DrawSingleObject` is called once

Comment: Thank to your help I've written some pseudocode,hoping its ok now (can't test it directly right now): 
http://pastebin.com/g2GpwjmR

Remembering to free texture memory every time I change the loaded model.My need is to use glTexCoord2f(t1,t2) to load texture on a not trivial object.I understand its use on a cube but i cant figure out how to use it on a model like a face (imagine a single mesh with a single texture and a lot of vertices).There are vertices coordinates to which I have to attach the texture,but how to choose the value t1,t2 for every face of the original post code?

Comment: @nicolagenesin well, texture coordinates are handled just like normals are. You either read them from a file (which you would with complex meshes like human faces) or you generate them at runtime (there's a lot of different methods of texture projection). But usually you only generate texture coordinates yourself if you generated the mesh yourself. Usually, if you read the mesh from a file you should also read the texture coordinates from it.

Comment: As for your specific case, "I think my main problem is that I render iterating through faces,while the textures' vertex list is generic (binded to a mesh and not to faces)." I really don't know what API you're using but if you bind position and normals to `Face`s then you should bind texture coordinates to it too. If that's not then you should consult whoever wrote that class (or the documentation to it) and ask them how they envisioned it to be used.